# A line break inside a string when printing?

Tags: arduino

I have a string that i have to send to some module from the arduino serial. 
Within that string there is a line break symbol like `\n`, so it should be :

```
c:send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n")
```

that is being sent to the module from serial. but what happens is that the serial is taking that string and go one line down , which i dont want him to do, i want him to send it like that with that sign

```
Serial.println(F( c:send(\"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\") ) );
```

would take that \n and remove it and go one line down.
I would like to keep the \r\n\ to send exactly like this to the module,

How would you let him stop doing this ( for example when you want to add a `"` inside a string you put a `\` before , and i am looking for something similar)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another `\` before the `\n`, so you'll have something like this:

```
Serial.println(F( c:send(\"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\n\") ) )
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Serial.print() function will print in the same line.
Whatever is suppose to be terminated at the end of the string should go in Serial.println() function.

So use:
`Serial.println("c:send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")")`.